# Read ssl certificate with .cer format in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, https, openssl

I want to execute the following :

```
certificate = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read("cert.cer"))
key = ??
ca_certificate = ??


RestClient::Resource.new(
'https://example.com',
:ssl_client_cert  => certificate,
:ssl_client_key   =>  key,
:ssl_ca_file      =>  ca_certificate,
:verify_ssl       =>  OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
).get
```

I have certificate which is in .cer format . I am able to read the certificate but not able to read the key and ca_certificate. Let me know how I can read the key as well as ca_certificate

Comment: Do you have the `key` and `ca_cert` available?

Comment: @MikeMackintosh : Do I need them separately ? I have a certificate file . Can I not extract the information from it ?

Comment: Your key will be in it's own file, and always should be (since this is public/private key infrastructure we're talking about). The CA Cert may be bundled sometimes in your `cert.cer` file, but not always. What you should do is see if it's bundled, if not, find out who the CA is, and download their root cert and use these new files in your code. Take a look at this, where I do something similar to generate OpenVPN client certificate files https://www.mikemackintosh.com/generating-openvpn-client-certs-with-ruby/